# Can I sort elements of an array in mongo with a built in?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I have this mongo document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fd40e781ddcb34819ac21e"),
    "name" : "fred",
    "fruits_i_like" : [
        "pear",
        "apple",
        "banana"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fd40fa81ddcb34819ac21f"),
    "name" : "barney",
    "fruits_i_like" : [
        "pear",
        "apple",
        "peach"
    ]
}
```

can I sort the subkeys so that I get

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fd40e781ddcb34819ac21e"),
    "name" : "fred",
    "fruits_i_like" : [
        "apple",
        "banana",
        "pear"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fd40fa81ddcb34819ac21f"),
    "name" : "barney",
    "fruits_i_like" : [
        "apple",
        "peach",
        "pear"
    ]
}
```

i.e  - I don't really care about the ordering of the documents, but each time a document is printed in the find cursor, the list of fruits in the subkey should be sorted. I can do this with passing a custom javascript function to `forEach()` on the `find()` - but I wondered if there was a more built in way with the build in mongo features.

Comment: You may not be aware that the JavaScript `sort` function can take a sorting function. `results.sort(function(a,b) { return a.name < b.name; })` and done, our mongo results are now sorted by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note operations such as [forEach](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) are iterators and you would have to do your sort actions on every item you retrieve. While this might be fine for some cases, there are a lot of reasons why this is not what you want. Particularly if you want to do any meaningful filtering of the content in inner arrays.

You can do a lot with array manipulation in the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), so to return your results with the array items sorted:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Unwind the array elements into each document
    {$unwind: "$fruits_i_like"},

    // Sort on the array key
    {$sort: { fruits_i_like: 1 }},

    // Push the elements back into an array
    {$group: { 
        _id: {_id: "$_id", name: "$name"}, 
        fruits_i_like: {$push: "$fruits_i_like"}
    }},

    // Restore the original document form
    {$project: { _id:0, _id: "$_id", name: "$_id.name", fruits_i_like: 1}}
])
```

So the use of [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) *denormalizes* in a way so that you can do other operations with the inner elements. Also the [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/) command returns a cursor in latest drivers just like `find`, and will do so internally in future releases.

Of course if you want your documents to *always* have sorted array, look at the [$sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort) modifier for use in [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) actions.

Comment: I'm not sure you need the square brackets, Seems that aggregate is a variadic function that you just supply as many arguments as you need to. Having said that, this is great - I'll happily accept this as the answer. The `unwind` function is a winner!